# What is causing this error whenever I try to push to gist.github.com when pushing to all of my regular repositories work just fine?

Tags: github, sha, gist

Why does this occur?  This is a secret gist, and I removed the PII from the block of code below:

```
user@NT696918742080085 MINGW64 ~/AppData/Roaming/Code/User (master)
$ git push -u origin master
The authenticity of host 'gist.github.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? no
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/a/421084/632320) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Check first if your key is properly recognized:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

Then, following "[Pushing to gist](https://dev.to/onmyway133/pushing-to-gist)", double-check your gist SSH URL, or try (with [2FA activated](https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors/#provide-access-token-if-2fa-enabled)), an HTTPS URL.